# what is "pixel-aligned" and "aligned" (PIFu paper)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I'm new in CV. When I read paper, I met something about "align". For example, in *[PIFu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05172)* we have "pixel-aligned". I would like to know what is "align" exactly. Any response will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: link to the paper.

Comment: [direct link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05172). I've edited the question to add this info. -- I'd never have bet on that from the little information in the question. looks very plausible though, especially adding context from other questions by OP. I also didn't notice that "pifu" was a word of significance.